# Deserialise JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, deserialization

I'm consuming a WebService and deserialising the object this way:

```
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Member>(result);
```

This is the `JSON`

```
{
   "CREATE": [
   {
      "isValidMemberPassword": true,
      "member_eid": 13
   }],
   "DATE": "2017-01-26 11:25:20"
}
```

These are the classes to deserialise:

```
public class Member
{
    public List<Create> Create { get; set; }
    public string DATE { get; set; }
}

public class Create
{
    public bool isValidMemberPassword { get; set; }
    public int member_eid { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that my `Create` object isn't being created with the values received. All of the values are `null`. The `Member` object is being correctly created. I'm a noob at C#.

Comment: strange, works for me

Comment: Try to use public `List<Create> CREATE { get; set; }` in stead of `public List<Create> Create { get; set; }`. Can you say me it's working of not?

Comment: Maybe "Create" is a keyWord? try using CREATE

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn worked ;)

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to use a class generator like http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Works for me also, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ayn7M5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for JSON convert, your properties must be equal with the properties of your JSON code. If you have troubles to convert, you could use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/).

I see that the properties of the JSON code are not in the right format rules *(Properties names in camelcase)*. To correct this you could use the attribute `JsonProperty` with first parameter the JSON property name. See code below:

```c#
public class Member
{
    [JsonProperty("CREATED")]
    public List<Create> Created { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DATE")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class Create
{
    [JsonProperty("isValidMemberPassword")]
    public bool IsValidMemberPassword { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("member_eid")]
    public int MemberEid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below mentioned classes

```
public class CREATE
{
    public bool isValidMemberPassword { get; set; }
    public int member_eid { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<CREATE> CREATE { get; set; }
    public string DATE { get; set; }
}
```